# How to backport jquery.on to jquery.bind?

Tags: jquery

I absolutely must adapt this single row to be run with the old jquery 1.51

```
this.on({'mouseenter.hoverIntent':handleHover,'mouseleave.hoverIntent':handleHover}, cfg.selector)
```

I'm not able to under stand the syntax. I know that the portion inside burly brackets are events, but what does it mean this ?

```
'mouseenter.hoverIntent':handleHover
```

and this ?

```
'mouseleave.hoverIntent':handleHover
```

The code is the last row of the script taken from [here](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.js)

I'm doing this backport because .on is available only since 1.7, and I'm using 1.5.1, and I cannot upgrade, definitively sad thing.

adminbar.find('li.menupop').hoverIntent({
            over: function(e){
                if ( disableHoverIntent )
                    return;

```
            $(this).addClass('hover');
        },
        out: function(e){
            if ( disableHoverIntent )
                return;

            $(this).removeClass('hover');
        },
        timeout: 180,
        sensitivity: 7,
        interval: 100
    });
```

I just tried to simply replace with

```
return this.bind({'mouseenter.hoverIntent':handleHover,'mouseleave.hoverIntent':handleHover}, cfg.selector);
```

I got no error now, but, simply, it not works, menu opening on mouse hover is no more triggered

** HOW THIS CODE IS USED ? **

```
adminbar.find('li.menupop').hoverIntent({
        over: function(e){
            if ( disableHoverIntent )
                return;

            $(this).addClass('hover');
        },
        out: function(e){
            if ( disableHoverIntent )
                return;

            $(this).removeClass('hover');
        },
        timeout: 180,
        sensitivity: 7,
        interval: 100
    });
```

***IMPORTANT NOTE 2***

Trying to dump `cfg.selector` give an `undefined`. So I actually don't know how to correctly dump this extension to the selected element.

Comment: Better if you http://jsfiddle.net/ your code

Comment: Just replace in plugin any reference to `on/off` with `bind/unbind`: http://jsfiddle.net/h29oh09t/

Comment: Sorry, I've not tried to simply replace, because I was tring to understand the syntax before

Comment: @A.Wolff: see my edited question, simply replacing causes no error, but doesn't work!

Comment: Is `cfg.selector` defined ?, can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: cfg.selector is undefined, I edited my question to add the exact call

Comment: @realtebo What is `disableHoverIntent` ? http://jsfiddle.net/h29oh09t/1/ ?

Comment: @guest271314 you're right: disableHoverIntenet is a boolean, and its always false if site is not watched through a mobile browser. Your jsFiddle is simply great, and works. Write a complete answer and I will choose and upvote !

Comment: @a-wolff composed initial jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h29oh09t/; modified minimally reflected at updated post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit, Updated

Following and utilizing jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h29oh09t/1/ provided by @a-wolff , modified minimally at

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.hoverIntent = function (handlerIn, handlerOut, selector, cfg) {

        // default configuration values
        var cfg = cfg || {
            interval: 100,
            sensitivity: 6,
            timeout: 0
        };
```

try

```
var adminbar = $("ul");

var disableHoverIntent = false;

adminbar.find('li.menupop').hoverIntent({
    over: function (e) {
        if (disableHoverIntent) return;

        $(this).addClass('hover');
    },
    out: function (e) {
        if (disableHoverIntent) return;

        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    }
}, null, {timeout: 180,
        sensitivity: 7,
        interval: 100});
```

---

> but what does it mean this ?
>
> `'mouseenter.hoverIntent':handleHover`

The `.hoverIntent` portion of

`mouseenter.hoverIntent`

appear to be a `namespace`

See [.on() - Event names and namespaces](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)

Comment: I know basic namespace usage, but what about ':handleHover', what is its role?

Comment: @realtebo The handler portion; or function to call on `'mouseenter.hoverIntent'` `event` .  See _"Example: Attach multiple event handlers simultaneously using a plain object."_ http://api.jquery.com/on/#example-8

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `on()` with [`bind()`](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) should do what you need it to for jQuery 1.5.  The object passed in consists of keys that represent the event type and the values of that object represent the event handler. So in your case of `'mouseenter.hoverIntent':handleHover`, the event type is `mouseenter.hoverIntent` which is a custom event that gets triggered somewhere else in the code. Once that event is triggered the `handleHover` function is called.

Comment: see my edited question, simply replacing causes no error, but doesn't work!

Comment: Probably because of the selector `cfg.selector` that you have as the last argument. jQuery 1.5 expects the last argument to be your handler, not a selector. You can either go and modify the handler to select that element that `cfg.selector` is selecting or you can try binding directly to `cfg.selector`. It really depends on what the rest of the code is doing.

Comment: Yes, cfg.selector is 'undefined'. I edited my question to add the way the call actually used this extension. How to replace cfg.selector?